# Método DELETE utilizando href - NodeJS

Tags: html5, node.js

Estou carregando algumas informações do banco sendo que uma das colunas será um link que vai excluir uma infomação.

Por estar em uma table, o href do link está assim:

```
href="/delete/ID(vem do template engine)?_method=DELETE
```

Ele deveria ir para a minha rota que está assim:

```
router.delete('/delete/:_id', "Resultado do meu controller"));
```

A configuração do meu app.js para herdar os médotos PUT e DELETE está assim:

```
app.use(methodOverride('X­HTTP­Method'));
app.use(methodOverride('X­HTTP­Method­Override'));
app.use(methodOverride('X­Method­Override'));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

Dessa forma, existe mais alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para que ao clicar no link de delete seja redirecionado para a rota router.delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei fazendo dessa forma:

```
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="ExcluirRegistro('/stormtroppers/',{{stormtropper.id}})">Delete</a>
```

javascript:

```
function ExcluirRegistro(url, user_id) {
if (confirm('Deseja excluir o registro?')) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + user_id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function (res) {
            window.location.reload();
            return false;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            alert("Error deleting");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Mesmo assim... obrigado pelas informações!

Answer (score 0):

Quando o `href` é utilizado, o browser usa o método `GET` para fazer a requisição. Na documentação do módulo [method-override](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) está escrito que, por padrão, o único método HTTP que ele sobrescreve é o `POST`. Para que o módulo faça o que você precisa, será necessário que você passe os métodos que quer sobrescrever para o módulo. Mude a seguinte linha:

```
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

para:

```
app.use(methodOverride('_method', {methods: ['GET']}));
```

Se quiser manter o `POST` é só acrescentar a string `'POST'` no array de métodos permitidos do módulo.